# Grouped Regex to match a line that *sometimes* starts with spaces?

Tags: regex, wxwidgets

RegEx flavor: [wxRegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wxwidgets.html).

I am trying to create a "grouped" regex that matches a string that sometimes begins with a whitespace. When it doesn't begin with a whitespace, it begins with the target group (second parenthesized expression in the following sample). It is a relatively simple line made of a few predictable tokens and one portion of arbitrary text, e.g.

```
"good: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error "
"better: Sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium "
"best: Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas "
" ok: Sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium "
```

**Note**: The quoted characters are *not* part of my input. By introducing the quotes in my posting I am trying to make the boundaries of each line/string clearer.

The regex that I came up with to match the above in a "grouped" manner (i.e. that I can address each group separately for further processing) is:

```
(^\s*)(good|better|best|ok)(: )(.*)( $)
```

**Note**: \s is wxRegEx's class-shorthand escape for [[:space:]].

The problem is that this regex works only when the line actually begins with a space. Why? doesn't the '*' right after '\s' mean "0 or more occurrences of \s" ?

I know I am missing something fundamental here, but what is it?

Comment: Are the quote-characters part of your input?

Comment: Just a thought: what about moving the start-of-string char out of the group, and using the questionmark to make the group optional? `^( \s*)?(good|better|be ...`

Comment: @Bazzz I just tried your suggestion. Same (mis)behavior.

Comment: @slartidan No, the quoted characters are not part of my input. By introducing the quotes in my posting I tried to make the boundaries of each line/string clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this with `(^ *)` instead of `(^\s*)`? Is it possible you're wrong about the `\s` syntax? I don't know wxRegEx myself.

Comment: You nailed it. With (^ *) it works. But why? I know that \s is part of AREs only, but I made sure that the regex is compiled with wxRE_ADVANCED, which enables AREs. See documentation here: http://biolpc22.york.ac.uk/wx/docs/html/wx/wx_wxresyn.html#wxresynescapes Is it possible what I have should have used **two** backslashes?

Comment: Answering myself: Yes! I should have used **two** backslashes, because the actual regex is a string in the C++ source code.

Comment: @Regex Rookie: Sweet, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with wxRegEx, but if it is PCRE, I think you may want (^\s*)?(good|...

The '?' modifies the entire zero-or-more capture to make it zero-or-one.

Comment: This would make the `^` optional.

Answer (score 0):

I see no obvious error in your regex. Your interpretation of the `*` is also correct, of course. Do you maybe have some actual spaces in your expression? The space ( like ->  <- )   has no special meaning in regex and the engine will try to match it. If your first capturing group looked like `(^ \s*)` this would have the effect you describe.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird.. you are right that * should match 0 or more occurrences... Does moving the caret (^) outside the group make any difference?

Comment: I tried moving the caret outside of the group but it didn't make any difference.